# Mismatch in Custom Shape while migrating the code from Figma To Android

Tags: android, figma, ui-design

A Figma designer gave me a design file. I am trying to migrate the design file to Android. Except for 1 parallelogram I removed everything else. So the code below corresponds to just 1 shape.

When I check the Android code for that in Inspect in Figma, I see the code as pasted below. However what I see in my android does not look same as what I see in Figma. The parallelogram is tilted on Bottom Right in Figma, while it is not tilted in Android Studio.

I asked the designer and he said that he just took below left and right Conner's end point and moved them both to the right side. I am not sure why the tilt does not reflect in the path. Is there any other parameter which I can inspect in Figma which controls how the path is skewed.

```
<!-- Rectangle 3 -->
<View
android:id="@+id/rectangle_3"
android:layout_width="233.34dp"
android:layout_height="51.38dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="74.95dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="62.77dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_3"
android:elevation="20dp"
 />


<!-- drawable/rectangle_3.xml -->
<vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
android:width="233.34dp"
android:height="51.38dp"
android:viewportWidth="233.34"
android:viewportHeight="51.38"
 >

<group>

<clip-path
android:pathData="M5 0H228.343C231.105 0 233.343 2.23858 233.343 5V46.3827C233.343 49.1441 231.105 51.3827 228.343 51.3827H5C2.23858 51.3827 0 49.1441 0 46.3827V5C0 2.23858 2.23858 0 5 0Z"
/>

<path
android:pathData="M0 0V51.3827H233.343V0"
android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
/>

</group>

</vector>
```

This is how the tilted rectangle shows in Figma
[image: As shown in Figma]

This is the actual shape of rectangle
[image: The actual vector shape which I get in Android Studio as well]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes XML became mismatch from figma it self but you can use below code for the actual shape which you given in screenshot

Just make `shape.xml` file in `drawable` folder
Make Radius as per your design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#C4C4C4" />
        <padding android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right the code in the Inspect tab was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of obtaining the code from the Inspect tab, I used Export as SVG from Design Tab and then I got the correct path in the SVG file. I was able to then see the correct shape in Android. So the XML generated by Figma in the Inspect tab was incorrect.